# package java.servlet does not exist

Tags: java, servlets

It's my first Servlet program but even after adding the classpath of `servlet-api.jar` cmd gives me the same boring error saying: "java.servlet package does not exist"

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: cmd? are you compling from the command line?

Comment: yeah David the old and obselete "CMD" :-)

Comment: Why do not you consider using Maven for build this project. Will be time saving for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've a concrete servletcontainer installed. For example, [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org). At least the one where you target your webapplication to.

The Servlet API is then located in `/path/to/Tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar` file. You need to make sure that you include this path in the `-cp` or `-classpath` argument of the `javac` command. Assuming that you're currently inside the root folder of all your Java code:

```
javac -cp .:/path/to/Tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar com/example/SomeServlet.java
```

Or if it's on Windows, use semicolon `;` instead of colon `:` as path separator and if the path contains spaces like so `C:\Program Files\Tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar`, then surround the invididual path with quotes:

```
javac -cp .;"C:\Program Files\Tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar" com/example/SomeServlet.java
```

Comment: Is that the literal error or a typo? It should be `javax.servlet`. See also the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html

Comment: wats a literal error and wats a typo ?? i am not a good programmer buddy jst trying to become

Comment: Euh, that was just English. Have you copypasted the exact error, or have you typed it over and forgot the `x`? A typo means a typing mistake.

Comment: What does the error say? "java.servlet does not exist" or "javax.servlet does not exist"

Comment: " package javax.servlet does not exist "

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548163/java-servlet-programming-errror gives me the same kind of error !!!!

Comment: Okay, then the value of `-cp` argument is definitely invalid. Fix the path. Watch out with typos and uppercase/lowercase. Oh please be sparingly with exclamation marks. You don't need to yell to me :)

Comment: n now wen i gave it javac -cp C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\lib\servlet-api.jar it says " no source files " !!!

Comment: You forgot to specify the source file. It's the path to the `.java` file of your servlet, like as `com/example/SomeServlet.java` part in my answer. You also forgot to add the current folder `.` to the classpath. You need to use the same command syntax as I posted in my answer. You only need to change the `-cp` to reflect your actual path: `javac -cp .;"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\lib\servlet-api.jar" com/example/SomeServlet.java`

Comment: n now the most irritating thing comes up ... it says "javac" is not recognised as an internal or external command .... u must be getting irritated ... but i guess by mistake i closed dat Cmd n cos of this its giving this error ..... any suggestions 4 this error ???

Comment: If you write in normal English like an adult instead of in street/SMS/chat talk with all those cryptic abbreviations like a child, I would be less irritated :) As to the concrete problem, if `javac` does not exist, then it means that the path to `jdk/bin` is not been added to `%PATH%` environment variable. Configure it in advanced system properties by computer properties so that it get applied on every single opened prompt.

Comment: yeah i will take care of it now on wards ... as of now i guess Eclipse will be the only solution for me ... i will definitely irritate you some other day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're still not set up correctly.  Double-check everything your classpath, print out the PATH in that particular CMD window and make sure that JAR is there.  Sounds like you're not using Eclipse, so you'll have to do a lot of this confusing set-up work by hand.

Comment: the class path i gave is correct to my knowledge its CATALINA_HOME :C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26 for tomcat & JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03 for java ... i used ' set classpath=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\lib\servlet-api.jar ' still it shows me the same error

Answer (score 0):

With dynamic web projects (eclipse) it should be automatically added. If not- just download the jar and add it to the class path.

Comment: The servlet container should have this in the class path (tomcat/lib/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Servlet is of `javax.servlet` and not `java.servlet` package. That might be your problem. Organize your servlet import in your code.

---

To run a servlet on Tomcat, you must place your WAR file (that contains the compiled Servlet) under `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps` folder and run Tomcat from command line by calling `startup` (which calls startup.bat file, and assuming you're in `TOMCAT_HOME\bin` folder).

Comment: doesn't make any difference in the number of errors :-( even aftr doing dat

Comment: @user672390, still, now that we've eliminated the import, let's sort out your classpath. How are you running your servlet?

Comment: Servlet weren't meant to run on command prompt. It **must** run under a Servlet container.

Comment: yeah i mean to say i am using Tomcat manually not though ECLIPSE and stuff ....... but to run  this when i use the javac command it gives the above error